# How to matched the column from 2 different tables using php

Tags: php, mysqli

From the code, I want these 2 tables **(personal and information)** to compare whether it has the same **location** or not. If there is a matched, I want to display the data from **personal table** as stated at the comment.

```
$selectall = "SELECT * FROM information";
$stmt = mysqli_query($connection, $selectall);

$compare = "SELECT * FROM personal INNER JOIN information ON personal.location = information.location";
$comparing = mysqli_query($connection, $compare);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
   $output .= '<tr>
               <td>' .$row['name']. '</td>
               <td>' .$row['location']. '</td>
               <td>' .$row['postal']. '</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td>//This is where I want to show the matched data from personal table</td>
               </tr>';
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written?

Comment: `$row` will contain data from the matching rows in both tables.

Comment: okay, and how to display the data from the other table?

Comment: in the while loop, i only compute the $stmt. is it possible to get the data from $comparing ?

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_array($comparing)`. There's no need for `$stmt` at all.

Comment: is this consider as showing the two tables?

Comment: When you use a join, the result contains columns from both matching rows in the two tables.

Comment: I've tried it only shows the match row from both table. What i want is to display all the row from the **information** table, and at the same time to display any matched and unmatched data from **location** table

Comment: You should use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to include rows that don't have a match in `personal`.

Comment: still the same, only providing an empty row for the unmatched data

Answer (score 0):

I think what you needed is the results from `$comparing` query and not the `$selectall`.

If you want specific columns to be returned, the SQL can be manipulated toi return only the columns needed. e.g:

`SELECT column_from_information, other_column_you_want, personal.location FROM personal INNER JOIN information ON personal.location = information.location`

The idea is you can define columns with prepended table names i.e. personal.name, information.location, etc.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($comparing)) {
   $output .= '<tr>
           <td>' .$row['name']. '</td>
           <td>' .$row['location']. '</td>
           <td>' .$row['postal']. '</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td><!--Matched Data--></td>
           </tr>';
}
```

Comment: .$row['name']. , .$row['location']. , .$row['postal'] is actually from the "information" table. I want to display both table inside the while loop. How can i do that?

Comment: you mean columns from both tables? what are the columns needed?

Comment: The correct variable is `$comparing`, not `$compare`.

Comment: the location from personal table

Comment: @nzrnfourtwenty The location from `personal` is the same as the location from `information` because the query says `ON personal.location = information.location`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get everything in `information`, even if it doesn't have a match in `personal`, use an outer join. For rows that don't have a match, the columns from `personal` will contain `null`.

You should select the columns you want explicitly. If you use `SELECT *` and there are columns with the same name in both tables, `$row['columnname']` gets the value from the second table, which will be `null` when there's no match. Since you want the value from the first table, select it specifically.

```
$compare = "SELECT i.name, i.location, i.postal, p.somecolumn, p.anothercolumn FROM information AS i 
            LEFT JOIN personal AS p
            ON p.location = i.location";
$comparing = mysqli_query($compare);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comparing)) {
    $output .= '<tr>
           <td>' .$row['name']. '</td>
           <td>' .$row['location']. '</td>
           <td>' .$row['postal']. '</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td>' . $row['somecolumn'] . '</td>
           <td>' . $row['anothercolumn'] . '</td>
           </tr>';
}
```

Comment: im getting confused right now. Okay first thing first, i want to display all the data from the **information** table and(with) all matched data (based on location) from the **personal** just right below the the **information** data row in the $output. If there is no other data that is match from (personal.location = information.location), an empty result from the **personal** should be appear not the data from the **information**

Comment: correction:  If there is no other data that is match from (personal.location = information.location), an empty result from the **personal** should be appear. Because right now when im using left join, the data from **information** doesnt show up

Comment: * the data from **information** doesnt show up if there's an unmatched

Comment: fyi, both table has only same column name which is "location"

Comment: If you do it like I showed, the data from `information` should show up. You can't use `SELECT *` because then the same column name `location` will get the data from `personal`, not `location`, and when there's no match it will be empty.